# Plot ERA-INTERIM using R

Tags: r, netcdf

I have downloaded temperature data (netcdf) from ECMWF ERA-INTERIM [(click here to download the file)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3heau3wfydb4dag/netcdf-atls13-a562cefde8a29a7288fa0b8b7f9413f7-ORIAcW.nc?dl=0), but when I try to plot it, it seems incomplete. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(ncdf) 
library(raster)

UK <- getData("GADM",country="GBR",level=1)
england <- UK[UK$NAME_1 == 'England', ]

# To convert longitude from range [0,360] to [-180,180]
x <- rotate(raster(x = "netcdf-atls13-a562cefde8a29a7288fa0b8b7f9413f7-ORIAcW.nc", varname="t2m"))

plot(x, ext=extent(england))
plot(england, add=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bug. It has been fixed in raster 2.4-24 (available via R-Forge). Here is a work-around for this particular case:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster("netcdf-atls13-a562cefde8a29a7288fa0b8b7f9413f7-ORIAcW.nc", varname="t2m")
x <- rotate(r)
x[, 240] <- r[1:240,1]
```